# What will the explorer do when I use the fuction "Copy Link To text"?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to simulate it, but besides en/decoding, it will also designedly ignore part of the content, and I'm not sure is there more features I don't know.

Btw, maybe there is some diffrence when achieving it between Chrome, Edge and other modern explorers?

I think I've know the common en/decoding details in it. I prefer a complete document which I didn't find.